# Why is IE taking forever to open website via Selenium Web driver?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I wrote some code to open up a website and click on a button in IE . But every time I run the code , for some reason IE keeps loading for at least 10 seconds shows http://localhost:10450/ in the address bar.

Every time I run the code, it shows a different port number, but shows the same “local host” addressee in the addressee bar for at least 10-15 seconds. Why is this happening? I am trying to check the code for other issues, but I can’t even get to it if this isn’t resolved first. Sometimes it even shows the error message that says

**"Can’t reach this page
•Make sure the web address http://localhost:39790 is correct
"**

What could be causing this?

Comment: "*I wrote some code*" - Show us your code. Without seeing the code, we can only speculate.

Comment: Here it is. https://imgur.com/TbfOxzX

Comment: You should really take the [Tour], as well as take a look at the [HowToAsk-page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). TL;DR: Don't post image of code, post the code and edit your question instead of hiding relevant information in the comment section.

Comment: any error it's throwing?

Answer (score 0):

This was the error shown on IE 
Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND

Checked this error on youtube and reset IE AND now it works!!!

Thanks everyone!!!